# PostgreSQL - must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

This query works locally, but doesn't work on Heroku for some reason.

```
2014-06-26T00:45:11.334388+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column 
"conversations.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an 
aggregate 
function
```

This is the SQL.

```
Conversation.joins("INNER JOIN notifications ON 
notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id AND 
notifications.type IN ('Message') INNER JOIN receipts 
ON receipts.notification_id =  notifications.id WHERE 
notifications.type = 'Message' AND (receipts.receiver_id = #{a.id} 
AND receipts.receiver_type = 'Profile') AND conversations.id 
IN #{active_conversations_ids} ORDER BY conversations.updated_at DESC")
```

I tried doing distinct and it did not work, and I tried group_by('conversation_id')

## the to_sql

```
SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN 
notifications ON notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id 
AND notifications.type IN ('Message') INNER JOIN receipts 
ON receipts.notification_id =  notifications.id WHERE
notifications.type = 'Message' AND (receipts.receiver_id = 104 
AND receipts.receiver_type = 'Profile') AND conversations.id 
IN (…) ORDER BY conversations.updated_at DESC"
```

Comment: (1) Why are you putting a WHERE and ORDER BY in a `joins` call? (2) What does the whole query look like?

Comment: @muistooshort I used a select call but it returns a string or something bizzarre. The select call returns the right thing --admittably a little hacky, but I just need it to work and work efficiently.

Comment: The group_by would work, you just need to select the columns you want to group on which at this time you're doing `select "conversations".*`

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy can you be more specific please! = (

Comment: Can you show the Conversation, Notification and Receipt models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as adding

```
GROUP BY conversations.id
```

which ends up looking like

```
Conversation.joins("INNER JOIN notifications ON 
notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id AND 
notifications.type IN ('Message') INNER JOIN receipts ON 
receipts.notification_id = notifications.id WHERE 
notifications.type = 'Message' AND (receipts.receiver_id = #{self.id}) AND 
conversations.id IN #{active_conversation_ids} GROUP BY 
conversations.id ORDER BY conversations.updated_at DESC")
.select('conversations.id, conversations.updated_at')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the SQL in your server window, if you are running the app in local machine.

It is a good practice to keep the joins where they belong to.

```
Conversation.where('id' => active_conversations_ids).joins(
"INNER JOIN notifications ON notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id 
  AND notifications.type IN ('Message') 
INNER JOIN receipts ON receipts.notification_id = notifications.id 
  AND (receipts.receiver_id = #{a.id} AND receipts.receiver_type = 'Profile')"
).order('updated_at')
```

And for the better readability, you can use notifications with symbols.

```
Conversation
.find_all_by_id(active_conversations_ids)
.joins(:notifications, :receipts).where({   
    notifications: { type: 'Message' }, 
    receipts: { receiver_id: a.id, receiver_type: 'Profile'}
})
.order('updated_at')
```

My final suggestion would be to google for named scopes.

http://zachholman.com/2010/01/simplifying-rails-controllers-with-named_scopes/